# Antonym for retrieve

Tags: antonyms

Is there a word similar to `retrieve` which means the opposite? (like the words send and receive) I do not know if there is such a combination. I have been thinking about words which mean the opposite my self, words such as:

Drop off.
Send.
Perform.

But I have no idea if the word retrieve has an actual counter part.

**EDIT**
I'm a programmer and am using retrieve to retrieve data from a task I created earlier, I would now like to provide information to that task.

Comment: Retrieve has a lot of meanings. It can't have an antonym unless any context is given. If you retrieve something from your memory, the antonym is very obvious.

Comment: Could you provide an example sentence? An antonym may be context-dependent.

Comment: @Rathony You could suppose retrieve is used in that context. (though more of an electronic memory :P )

Comment: In the context you imply I think you would speak of *stored* data.

Comment: @StoneyB does "Storing data" not imply you will do nothing with the data you stored? aren't things stored for safe keeping so nothing happens to it? In the context i'm looking for the data gets processed.

Comment: Why would you store it if you weren't going to do something with it?

Comment: "Post" or "transmit" are a couple more words that come to mind.

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat: You have to figure out what metaphor you're using. What actually happens in data retrieval is that a location is specified to an input, which copies N bytes from that location, then repeats with another location, until told to stop. _Retrieve_ is a complex word: it means, with some Direct Object, 'go towards DO, find DO, pick up and continue holding DO, and return to starting point.' In sequence. That's way too complex to have an easy antonym. So you have to use a metaphor.

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat: So, is this a journey metaphor? In RAM, everything is the same distance away; that's no help. How about  typesetting? A hand printer retrieves a piece of type from the correct box when needed, and replaces it when finished. Using only a hand motion, with no significant distance parameter -- everything is rapid precision. And it doesn't matter whether you put it back in the same location, as long as you change the label so you can retrieve it again.

Comment: @Rathony - Yeah, for me the antonym is *forget*.

Comment: For data, the antonym of *retrieve* is surely **serve**. Data retrieval is a service, usually provided by a server of some sort.  As has been said, for some meanings ("My dog retrieved the stick I threw.") there may be no useful antonym, or a very different one.

Comment: I think that one needs to distinguish between an antonym and what I would call a "reciprocal word".  The "antonym" of *retrieve* would be a word that means to not retrieve.

Comment: To not retrieve would be the absence of "retrieval", wouldn't it, @HotLicks?  I was thinking that the literal opposite would be to dispatch, which PCARR just posted as an answer

Comment: ***Put***. As others have indicated, it all depends on the specific context. But in general, *retrieve* and *fetch* mean essentially *get*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dispatch](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dispatch) may be suitable for you.

"To send with purpose".

Answer (score 2):

In a programming context the first thing that comes to mind when you mention 'retrieve data' is that it was previously **stored** and waiting for you to come and get it.

Otherwise you would use 'calculate' instead of retrieve when it's freshly generated data or 'receive' when another system/process provides the data to you.

Other options for **store** depending on your setup could be:

- feed
- provide
- send
- transmit
- serve

All of these words and their derivaties are used in technical specs regularly. For example: data feeds, data providers, data transmission, etc.

Check perhaps with your colleagues to see if there is a generally accepted word you can use. As there is no clear-cut answer it might be best to follow convention.

Answer (score 1):

The word 'retrieve' in your context means 'to bring back'. The right antonym should be '**abandon**'.

Comment: You mean *abandon*?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Retrieve means to bring the stored data back/again. If you do not bring them back,  you leave or abandon them.

Answer (score 0):

In the context you described, [upload](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upload) could work as defined in Merriam-Webster:

> to transfer (as data or files) from a computer to the memory of
>   another device (as a larger or remote computer)

1. She uploaded the pictures from her digital camera to her computer.
2. Upload files to the Internet

As in the No. 2 example, you can use *upload* as an antonym of "download/retrive".

You can also consider using *[return](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/return)* as well. You retrive something and return.

> To bring, give, send, or take (something) to the place that it came
>   from or the place where it should go

Answer (score 0):

The antonym for retrieve is **lose**, i.e. fail to retrieve.

In addition, consider the adjective **unretrieved.**

> unretrieved: not retrieved: [*unretrieved data*](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=OWaeBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA351&lpg=PA351&dq=%22unretrieved+data%22&source=bl&ots=-CHZlj4Hej&sig=SjiCfNzqlX9zMJBVjvzfv5b6Dqw&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMI1t7oheTHyAIVSD0UCh3bhAC8#v=onepage&q=%22unretrieved%20data%22&f=false)

[**OED**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unretrieved)

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm resurrecting an old post but I can't stand the suggestions given.
"abandon","To send with purpose", "lose", "unretrieved"?  Seriously?
You guys are all crazy word nerds.

Vincent, if you think of memory as a little box, then the software "stores" data in memory and then "retrieves" it from memory.  If you think of memory as a notebook, then the software "writes" data on the memory and then "reads" it from the memory.

Yes, data is being transferred, sent, posted, whatever, but that's just the way the goal is achieved, and the goal is to store data in a relatively permanent place for later use.

The data is not abandoned there because it will be retrieved later.  (Imagine telling your kid you are going to abandon her in school, lol)

The data is not lost there because you know where to find it, where you put it, of course.